# Which method of initializing and using atomic_flag is better?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20, atomic, wait

I see two ways of writing the below example code. **METHOD 1** sets the two flags to `true` in `main()` and the two threads `wait()` on `true`. **METHOD 2** does the exact opposite. It doesn't set the flags in `main` thus the threads `wait()` on `false`. Once the first flag is set to `true` from `main`, the first thread awakes and `clear()`s it and enters the critical section (incrementing `data`). The two methodss essentially do the same thing (sending a notification to the other thread) but with inverted flag values. And both return the same expected value from `main` (13).

**METHOD 1**:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>


void func1( int& data,
            std::atomic_flag& input_data_flag,
            std::atomic_flag& output_data_flag )
{
    input_data_flag.wait( true );
    input_data_flag.test_and_set( std::memory_order_acquire );

    data += 1;

    // Prepare the second flag and notify the second thread
    output_data_flag.clear( std::memory_order_release );
    output_data_flag.notify_one( );
}

void func2( int& data,
            std::atomic_flag& input_data_flag,
            std::atomic_flag& output_data_flag )
{
    input_data_flag.wait( true );
    input_data_flag.test_and_set( std::memory_order_acquire );

    data += 2;

    output_data_flag.clear( std::memory_order_release );
    output_data_flag.notify_one( );

}

int main( )
{
    std::atomic_flag flag1 { };
    std::atomic_flag flag2 { };

    flag1.test_and_set( std::memory_order_acquire );
    flag2.test_and_set( std::memory_order_acquire );

    int data { 10 };

    {
    std::jthread func1_thread { func1, std::ref( data ),
                                std::ref( flag1 ), std::ref( flag2 ) };
    
    std::jthread func2_thread { func2, std::ref( data ),
                                std::ref( flag2 ), std::ref( flag1 ) };

// here the first thread is finally notified to start its task
    flag1.clear( std::memory_order_release );
    flag1.notify_one( );
    }

    return data;
}
```

**METHOD 2**:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>


void func1( int& data,
            std::atomic_flag& input_data_flag,
            std::atomic_flag& output_data_flag )
{
    input_data_flag.wait( false );
    input_data_flag.clear( std::memory_order_release );

    data += 1;

    // Prepare the second flag and notify the second thread
    output_data_flag.test_and_set( std::memory_order_acquire );
    output_data_flag.notify_one( );
}

void func2( int& data,
            std::atomic_flag& input_data_flag,
            std::atomic_flag& output_data_flag )
{
    input_data_flag.wait( false );
    input_data_flag.clear( std::memory_order_release );

    data += 2;

    output_data_flag.test_and_set( std::memory_order_acquire );
    output_data_flag.notify_one( );
}

int main( )
{
    std::atomic_flag flag1 { };
    std::atomic_flag flag2 { };

    int data { 10 };

    {
    std::jthread func1_thread { func1, std::ref( data ),
                                std::ref( flag1 ), std::ref( flag2 ) };
    
    std::jthread func2_thread { func2, std::ref( data ),
                                std::ref( flag2 ), std::ref( flag1 ) };

// here the first thread is finally notified to start its task
    flag1.test_and_set( std::memory_order_acquire );
    flag1.notify_one( );
    }

    return data;
}
```

Which method is more efficient? Or are they effectively equivalent (though method 1 has 5 more assembly lines)?

And does method 2 even make sense? It doesn't look intuitive to me. For instance, each thread waits on a flag to become `true` and then clears it to `false` using `clear( std::memory_order_release )` and then enters the critical section which somehow does not seem ok in my opinion. Especially the memory order `std::memory_order_release` before writing to a shared resource seems awkward to me (shouldn't it always be `std::memory_order_acquire`?). What memory orders are correct and should be used in method 2?

Please correct me if anything is wrong here.

Comment: @Paul Sanders Updated the question.

Comment: Thanks, it's much clearer.  I don't have an opinion as to which is best, but others might and this should help them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a traditional "critical section".  If multiple threads called the same function with the same flags at once, you'd have a data race.  Mutual exclusion only comes from the chain of `.wait()` operations, and the way you're doing it doesn't require any expensive atomic RMW operations like `.test_and_set()`.

Synchronization only comes from `flag.wait(old,  seq_cst)` (where seq_cst is the default ordering for `.wait()`, like with all std::atomic operations).  This is overkill; this is where you want `acquire`.  [`.wait()` works](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/wait) *as if* it was doing `this->load(order)` in a loop, only returning after the compare is false (even if the underlying OS has some spurious wakeups, which is what makes it safe to use it this way without looping yourself and checking the flag value with `.test()`.)

You're right that a `release` operation before a store isn't useful to create synchronization for it, but even when you `TAS(acquire)` in method 1 you're not checking the return value so it doesn't do anything that `.wait(val, seq_cst)` didn't already do.

Where your Method 2 is actually broken is the `TAS(acquire)` after `data += 1;`.  That does not synchronize-with `.wait(seq_cst)`.  In practice it works on x86-64, where every atomic RMW is a full barrier (as strong as `seq_cst`), so only compile-time reordering could break it.  And even plain stores on x86-64 have release semantics.  And it probably works even on other ISAs if the waiting thread actually went to sleep on its first call to `.wait()`.  (I think your Method 1 is actually guaranteed correct by the ISO C++ standard.)

**`.wait(acquire)` would be appropriate.**  (It's guaranteed not to spuriously return early.)  It doesn't much matter whether you start with false or true, as long as you avoid `atomic_flag` which can only be set to `true` with an atomic RMW, which you have no use for.

If you want these functions to reset their incoming flags back to the original state before exiting (something this example doesn't rely on), you might as well just do a relaxed store of whatever value you want.

Your `main` reads the final value of `data` after synchronizing with the threads via `.join()` (implicit in their destructors), not by spin-waiting for the `output_data_flag` from the 2nd function to change.  Which wouldn't work; your first function changes it and the 2nd changes it back.  So if you were going to do that, you'd want a 3rd flag as the output from the 2nd function.

---

`atomic_flag` sucks and doesn't support plain store except via `.clear()`, only an expensive read-modify-write to set it to true.  **Use `atomic<bool>`**.  It's lock-free on all modern platforms.

```
#include <atomic>

void func1( int& data,
            std::atomic_bool& input_data_flag,
            std::atomic_bool& output_data_flag )
{
    input_data_flag.wait( false, std::memory_order_acquire );   // wait for true
    // input_data_flag.store( false, std::memory_order_relaxed );  // clear it back to false for later use??  Or make this a release-store after access to data if you want the thread that set it to be able to notice when we set it back?

    data += 1;

    // Prepare the second flag and notify the second thread
    output_data_flag.store( true, std::memory_order_release );
    output_data_flag.notify_one( );
}

// func2 is the same but with += 2
```

The `output_data_flag.store(true, release)` is the `mov   byte ptr [rbx], 1` instruction in clang's asm for x86-64 ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:45,endLineNumber:13,positionColumn:45,positionLineNumber:13,selectionStartColumn:45,selectionStartLineNumber:13,startColumn:45,startLineNumber:13),source:%27%23include+%3Catomic%3E%0A%0Avoid+func1(+int%26+data,%0A++++++++++++std::atomic_bool%26+input_data_flag,%0A++++++++++++std::atomic_bool%26+output_data_flag+)%0A%7B%0A++++input_data_flag.wait(+false,+std::memory_order_acquire+)%3B+++//+wait+for+true%0A++++//+input_data_flag.store(+false,+std::memory_order_relaxed+)%3B++//+clear+it+back+to+false+for+later+use%3F%3F++Or+make+this+a+release-store+after+access+to+data+if+you+want+the+thread+that+set+it+to+be+able+to+notice+when+we+set+it+back%3F%0A%0A++++data+%2B%3D+1%3B%0A%0A++++//+Prepare+the+second+flag+and+notify+the+second+thread%0A++++output_data_flag.store(+true,+std::memory_order_release+)%3B%0A++++output_data_flag.notify_one(+)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+func2+is+the+same+but+with+%2B%3D+2%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.699289229086936,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1600,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:34,endLineNumber:26,positionColumn:34,positionLineNumber:26,selectionStartColumn:9,selectionStartLineNumber:26,startColumn:9,startLineNumber:26),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+16.0.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.30071077091307,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)).  It appears that its `.wait()` doesn't optimistically test the flag first, to see if it's already different from what you wanted.  It unconditionally does an atomic increment of hash table of bookkeeping variables(?) and calls a library function.   So depending on your use-case, you might use this if you expect to something have the flag already set.  (Like here where the main thread has probably already stored to `flag1` before `func1` has even started running.)

```
    if (!input_data_flag.load(std::memory_order_acquire) ) {
        input_data_flag.wait( false, std::memory_order_acquire );
    }
```

The vast majority of the asm is the calls to `.wait()` and `.notify_one()`.   `.notify_one()` inlines except for the system call, which is conditional presumably on there being no waiters.

---

On some ISAs (including AArch64), there's a register that permanently reads as zero.  This makes storing `0` (`false`) slightly cheaper than any other value.  (Testing a load result for zero vs. non-zero isn't cheaper, even on x86 where variable-length instructions often make small things matter, `test eax, eax` / `jz` vs `jnz` makes no difference.  Or inside `wait()`, it would probably be doing `cmp` between two registers).

Once you get the inefficient `atomic_flag` with its `test_and_set()` out of the picture and use pure stores, things are pretty much symmetric and you can use whichever seems more semantically appropriate for your flags.

Starting false and becoming true for data ready is a good convention that makes sense to me.

Flags in static storage can go in the BSS instead of the `.data` section if they're initialized to zero, so prefer that.  And as part of a larger struct, can often be cheaply zeroed along with the surrounding members.  So having variables constructed as `false` initially is generally good, especially when you have multiple variables at once.  (Especially in a struct; GCC misses the optimization when multiple loose scalars are all zero-initialized, not struct members or array elements.)

Comment: You are right. I tried atomic_bool and it generates less code. The performance seems to be the same as atomic_flag. And it's somehow easier to reason about. So in the end, what should I use? I used your first code snippet.

Comment: @digito_evo: Generally use `atomic_bool`.  For a use-case where `atomic_flag` has exactly the operations you want, you might consider using it, but `atomic_bool` can do everything `atomic_flag` can.  (e.g. `.exchange(true)` to do test-and-set.)

Comment: I have another follow-up and related question regarding exception handling and thread exit but I need to post another question since the code is larger. I hope to see your insights on it as well.